# Saving vectors in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

I need to save my vectors layer back to PostGIS, which if I read correctly I can do using GeoServer, however I'm confused.  All the examples ask you to import a shapefile.  I don't have a shapefile.  This will be a empty vector layer on top of a couple of base layers which the user will add polygons, points etc. etc.

How do I create the tables to hold the vector data.  Also how do I know the structure of the tables.  e.g columns, column names, primary / foreign key, relationships etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add empty tables to PostGIS in Geoserver:

Before this view can be served by GeoServer, the following step is necessary to manually create the geometry_columns entry:

```
INSERT INTO geometry_columns VALUES ('','public','my_view','my_geom', 2, 4326, 'POINT' );
```

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/postgis.html

Comment: Hi @Mapperz.  I added the values above into the relevant geometry_columns table but when i go to add a new layer from my data store the entry is not available.  any ideas

Comment: did you CREATE TABLE them, too? The example above implies my_view has a point geometry field called my_geom